# O que é um site nível Triple-A ou AAA? O que preciso para meu site ser considerado um AAA em acessibilidade?

Tags: ux, webdesign, acessibilidade, ui, wcag

Considero a acessibilidade algo muito importante, porém acredito que tenho negligenciado muito essa boa prática e fui ler as [Diretrizes de Acessibilidade para Conteúdo Web (WCAG) 2.0](https://www.w3.org/Translations/WCAG20-pt-PT/). Então eu reparei que existe um graduação de acessibilidade que o site pode receber `A`, `AA` ou `AAA`.

> Para satisfazer as necessidades dos diferentes grupos e situações
>   foram definidos três níveis de conformidade:
>
> - A (o mais baixo)
> - AA
> - AAA (o mais elevado)

Além disso reparei que exite uma tabela com uns *badges* que vc pode usar no seu site caso ele se enquadre em um desses níveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Mas minhas dúvidas são:

- O que são esses `Levels` **A**, **AA** e **AAA**? Quais tipos de deficiência fazem parte de cada grupo?
- Quais são os critérios de cada um desses níveis? O que meu site precisa atender para ser pelo menos um `Level A` de acessibilidade?
- Exitem ferramentas de auditoria, ou alguma opção de `Extensão` ou do `DevTools` do Browser que eu possa usar para avaliar qual o nível atual de acessibilidade no meu site?
- A acessibilidade e a nota desse `Level` podem ser usado pelo Google como critério de ranqueamento do site? Posso ser punido por ter um site pouco acessível?

Comment: Hugo, inclui mais uma dúvida, quais grupos de necessidade atende cada `Level`. Pois em uma pesquisa com podemos identificar se nossas personas será atendida com o `level` *A* ou teria que ser *AAA*. Parabéns pela pergunta!

Comment: @David obrigado jovem! Inclui na minha pergunta a parte dos grupos e tipos de deficiência. A parte das personas acho que fugiria um pouco do escopo da pergunta, pois são casos particulares de cada projeto, traçar perfil de persona acho que envolveria coisa de mais para uma pergunta só rss

Comment: Boa tarde Hugo!
O site https://www.tawdis.net/?lang=pt# permite avaliar o nível de acessibilidade e destaca os pontos que atribuíram a classificação alcançada. Estes pontos podem orientar o atendimento às premissas de aumento da acessibilidade e consequentemente, classificação. Espero que seja útil :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL. DR.

> O que são esses Levels A, AA e AAA? Quais tipos de deficiência fazem
>   parte de cada grupo? Quais são os critérios de cada um desses níveis?
>   O que meu site precisa atender para ser pelo menos um Level A de
>   acessibilidade?

Existe um ranqueamento dos sites fornecidos pela W3(WCAG) baseando-se no quanto o seu site atende, ou pode vir a atender, o público, no qual `A`,`AA` e `AAA` são os níveis ,sendo o primeiro o menos o relavante, e o último o mais.
Para entender o funcionamento do mesmo é necessário compreender que o mesmo é dividido em 4 princípios para o desenvolvimento de um site:
 [perceptível, operável, compreensível e robusto.](https://www.w3.org/Translations/WCAG20-pt-PT/#intro-layers-guidance)

**Percepção**

- Os componentes de informações e interface do usuário devem ser apresentáveis ​​aos usuários de maneiras que eles possam perceber.
  As heurísticas de Nielsen tratam de diversos pontos de percepção, o quão fácil é de perceber o que cada componente/ do seu site.

**Operável**

- Os componentes da interface do usuário e a navegação devem ser operáveis(operacionais).

**Compreensível**

- operação e informações devem estar compreensíveis.

**Robusto**

- Deve ser robusto de informações suficientes para que uma grande maioria de pessoas(usuários) possam interpretar corretamente, incluindo tecnologias assistivas.

Trecho traduzido e adaptado do [site da WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/intro.html#introduction-fourprincs-head).

Dentre cada grande principio existe uma [série de avaliações](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?versions=2.0&showtechniques=128) , que ao final gerará uma nota e dirá se será ou não um site ranqueado.
Cada Avaliação está detalhada pelo site(em inglês), ficaria enorme colocar apenas uma delas, portanto não explicarei cada 1.

Para um  A existe um mínimo de requerimentos a serem atendidos. Os mesmos podem ser encontrados [aqui](https://www.wuhcag.com/wcag-checklist/).

> Exitem ferramentas de auditoria, ou alguma opção de Extensão ou do
>   DevTools do Browser que eu possa usar para avaliar qual o nível atual
>   de acessibilidade no meu site?

A W3 Fornece uma lista de [ferramentas](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/) de acessibilidade para utilização,todas que utilizei são gratuitas, ou uma quantidade de utilização é.
[image: Exemplo Funcional de uma das mesmas]
Este exemplo foi tirado de uma verificação feita neste [site](https://webaccessibility.com/)(consta na lista da WCAG).A mesma mostra uma lista com detalhamento do que pode ser melhorado e pode ser encontrado  na lista.

> A acessibilidade e a nota desse Level podem ser usado pelo Google como
>   critério de ranqueamento do site? Posso ser punido por ter um site
>   pouco acessível?

Primeiro precisamos entender o [algoritmo do google](https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/algorithms/) e sua  [pesquisa](https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing/). Ambos os links estão em português, inclusive o da pesquisa contempla um vídeo explicativo( e muito bem explicado) do  assunto.
A punição principal de um site sem usabilidade é apenas o seu "esquecimento",isto é, se o mesmo não infringir alguma lei ou ocasionar algum equívoco que possa lesar seu usuário. Sites com mais propagandas(em outros sites) tendem a terem mais indexes, consequentemente tendem a ficarem na frente dos outros.

**Nota:** Todas as Listas de melhorias, informações/instruções técnicas estão disponíveis no site da WCAG.

Historicamente falando esse tipo de ranqueamento(por letras, A,AA....) começou com o risco de crédito financeiro( calote), [pouco  antes da crise de 1873](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A2nico_de_1873), com a criação das primeiras agências de risco. É uma análise parecida ,entretanto , ao invés de verificar se seu site é bom, verifica se você pode ou não pagar.